# Planned Contrasts using statsmodels

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, hypothesis-test

I was wondering if there is a way to check planned contrasts using the package `statsmodels` (or any other python package).

**About the data:**

Imagine having a *dependent Variable* **Y** and *two independent variables (factors)*:

1. **A** with levels **a1,a2,a3** and
2. **B** with levels **b1,b2**

After calculating the ANOVA, which was straightforward, I now want to proof my hypotheses. In this case, I want to check if:

1. **H1:** *a1* vs. *a2,a3* -> `(2)*a1 + (-1)*a2 + (-1)*a3`
2. **H2:** *a2* vs. *a3* -> `(0)*a1 + (1)*a2 + (-1)*a3`

However, this is sadly not as straightforward as calculating the ANOVA.

**My approaches (so far):**

Starting from this basis:

```py
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_spss('fancy_dataset.sav')

 
linear_model = smf.ols(Y ~ C(A, Sum) * C(B, Sum), data = data).fit()
```

I tried the following:

**1. Using `linear_model.t_test()`**

The approach of using `t_test()` and passing an array containing the contrasts sadly doesn't work since `linear_model` does not contain the reference levels of the factors (i.e. *a1* and *b1* ). This would be sufficient for **H2** but sadly not for **H1**.

**2. Passing the Contrast in the formula**

The approach

```py
smf.ols(Y ~ C(A, [[2],[-1],[-1]]) * C(B), data = data).fit()
```

would not calculate results I would get using `JASP`, `JAMOVI`, or `SPSS`. As far as I know, it is important to use the `C(A, Sum)` and `C(B, Sum)` contrast to get the results as you would get using these statistics software.

The only documentation related to contrasts in statsmodels is a page about using the package `patsy` which is sadly more confusing than helpful.

After this dilemma, I would appreciate a solution. I am also open to other packages in python that may be able to solve this task.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Best regards!

Comment: In H1: a1 is by definition zero as reference level. Then, isn't H1 equivalent to testing a2 + a3 = 0?

Comment: you could also add `-1` to the formula than the constant is dropped and one reference level remains in the model.

Comment: Hi @Josef

Thank you for your answer! 

Yes,  *a1*  is as far as I know (if not set otherwise) the reference level. However, you would have to specify a1 as `-1` and a2 as `1` or vice versa in the used model. It works if you for example use `linear_model.t_test([0,-1,1,0,0,0])` but sadly not for **H2**. Adding `-1` would work if you wouldn't use `c(A, Sum)` in the formula or else the `Intercept` would be replaced with `C(Alcohol, Sum)[mean]`.